# предотвратить rerender и unmount

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

1. **next: 14.1.3**
2. **папка app**

**страница:**

после каждого нажатия на кнопку идет полная перересовка а **C** unmount-итца

```
import { A, B, C } from "@/components/some";
import { FC } from "react";

const Page: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>page</h2>
      <A />
      <B />
      <C />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

**компонент A:**

```
"use client";
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export const A = () => {
  console.log(`A`);
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const path = pathname + "?" + `some=${Math.random()}`;
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>A</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          router.push(path);
        }}
      >
        change query
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**компонент B:** как избежать rerender-а?

```
"use client";
export const B = () => {
  console.log(`B`);

  return <div>123</div>;
};
```

**компонент C:** почему тут происходит mount/unmount

```
"use client";
import { memo, useEffect } from "react";
export const C = memo(() => {
  console.log(`C`);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`mount C`);
    return () => {
      console.log(`unmount C`);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>123</div>;
});

C.displayName = "C";
```

Comment: Визуально похоже на то, что при роуте, идет обновление страницы и все компоненты заново устанавливаются

Comment: @SwaD ререндер-а да, просто можно history.location юзать и forceuUpdate тогда B/C не заредерятся заного. Остается понят почему C так себя видет, B вот не унмоунтится, если дабаить ефект внутр

Comment: @SwaD точнее наоборот какого черта B не унмоунтится) вроде бы должно по логике.

Comment: Ну так вы везде useEffect добавьте и посмотрите. Поведение должно быть одинаковое у всех компонентов внутри `Page`

Comment: @SwaD [B] не унмаунтится [C] унмоунтится : пробовал уже.